# Sorting by similarity in alphanumeric string MS SQL Server 2012

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I've inherited a project that is using a PHP script to access a SQL Server 2012 database. The application allows a user to input several parameters and make a request based on those parameters.

The piece I'm having problems with is a field that allows users to search for an item with a SKU beginning with a string of alphanumeric characters.

This is the query that was used by the project:

```
SELECT top 10 IB.LocalSKU
, Cast(Round(IB.GoalMargin, 2) AS Decimal(10,2)) AS GoalMargin
, CASE WHEN IB.MAP = 0 THEN NULL ELSE IB.MAP END AS Min
, IB.ProductCost
, IB.ShippingEstimate
, EB.Price AS CurrentPrice


FROM intra.InventoryBase IB INNER JOIN intra.DropshipChannelAdvisorSKUs CA
  ON IB.LocalSKU = CA.LocalSKU
LEFT JOIN intra.eBayQoHFeedback EB
  ON CA.ChannelAdvisorSKU = EB.SKU

WHERE LOWER(IB.LocalSKU) LIKE LOWER('$localSKU%')
  AND LOWER(SupplierID) LIKE LOWER('%$supplierId%')
  AND LOWER(IB.Category) LIKE LOWER('%$category%')
  AND LOWER(IB.Dropship) LIKE LOWER('%$dropship%');
```

I have noticed that the query returns the correct information, but not in a useful order.

I am not sure how to sort it so that the rows with SKUs most closely matching the $localSKU variable are ranked first.

I attempted this, but it didn't have the effect I hoped for:

```
ORDER BY Difference(IB.LocalSKU, '$localSKU%') ASC
```

I've also done some reading on Fuzzy String matching, but I'm not sure how to implement it here.

Is there an effective way to:

1. Search for a varchar starting with a given string
2. Order results based on the closeness of that string, then by value

Expected Result:

Parameters:

```
$localSKU = "FMCPL1CY00"; 
$supplierId = 87; 
$category = "Premium Floor Liners"; 
$dropship = True;
```

Expected results:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| FMCPL1CY00* | GoalMargin | 0 | ProductCost | ShippingEstimate | CurrentPrice |
| FMCPL1CY01* | GoalMargin | 0 | ProductCost | ShippingEstimate | CurrentPrice |
| FMCPL1CY02* | GoalMargin | 0 | ProductCost | ShippingEstimate | CurrentPrice |
| FMCPL1CY03* | GoalMargin | 0 | ProductCost | ShippingEstimate | CurrentPrice |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Actual Results:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| FMCPL1CH04221509 | GoalMargin | 0 | ProductCost | ShippingEstimate | CurrentPrice |
| FMCPM1SA0021302  | GoalMargin | 0 | ProductCost | ShippingEstimate | CurrentPrice |
| FMCPL1TY07801509 | GoalMargin | 0 | ProductCost | ShippingEstimate | CurrentPrice |
| FMCPL1TY05721502 | GoalMargin | 0 | ProductCost | ShippingEstimate | CurrentPrice |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you please show expected result and actual result

Comment: Also, can you provide some examples of `$localSKU`?

Comment: @TheGameiswar I added those for you, let me know if I can clarify further

Comment: @scsimon Done, let me know if there is anything else I can add

Comment: So we can remove first 8 symbols and order by remain string casted to int?

Comment: @gofr1 For this supplier, that would work, but in some cases there are alphabetic characters remaining in the local SKU. This would need to be elastic enough that a user could enter just "F" for the local SKU value and still get an answer.

Comment: @jacob-on-stackoverflow the pattern of `LocalSKU` may vary? Not always first 8 symbols are text, and other digit?

Comment: @gofr1 Correct, for example if we were talking about another supplier it could be: ZVW-355-023-F. That was pulled from our production database for this utility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT top 10 IB.LocalSKU
, Cast(Round(IB.GoalMargin, 2) AS Decimal(10,2)) AS GoalMargin
, CASE WHEN IB.MAP = 0 THEN NULL ELSE IB.MAP END AS Min
, IB.ProductCost
, IB.ShippingEstimate
, EB.Price AS CurrentPrice

,CASE WHEN IB.LocalSKU LIKE '$localSKU%' THEN 0  else 1 END as MyOrder

FROM intra.InventoryBase IB INNER JOIN intra.DropshipChannelAdvisorSKUs CA
  ON IB.LocalSKU = CA.LocalSKU
LEFT JOIN intra.eBayQoHFeedback EB
  ON CA.ChannelAdvisorSKU = EB.SKU

WHERE LOWER(IB.LocalSKU) LIKE LOWER('$localSKU%')
  AND LOWER(SupplierID) LIKE LOWER('%$supplierId%')
  AND LOWER(IB.Category) LIKE LOWER('%$category%')
  AND LOWER(IB.Dropship) LIKE LOWER('%$dropship%')

ORDER BY MyOrder ASC;
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: This gives me a good result with a slight adjustment: 

ORDER BY MyOrder ASC, IB.LocalSKU ASC;